# mixing text and citations in R markdown

Tags: r-markdown

Is it possible to mix regular text and citations in R markdown documents so that they looked as follows: (Author 2018; Methods)

Currently, I've tried `([@Author2018]; *Methods*)` which gives `((Author 2018); Methods)`, and [@Author2018; *Methods*] results in a knitting error.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!