# Is it possible to remove parentheses from in-text citations in R?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, bibtex

I'm trying to remove a parenthesis from a citation that is already within a parenthesis. At the moment my markdown text looks as follows:

```
The questionnaire Patient Health Questionnaire 9-Item Scale (PHQ-9; [@Kroenke2010]) was used to assess symptoms of depression.
```

Which ends up like this:

> The questionnaire Patient Health Questionnaire 9­Item Scale (PHQ­9; (Kroenke, Spitzer, Wil­liams, & Löwe, 2010)) was used to assess symptoms of depression.

I've tried to change the markdown text to (aka removing the brackets around the citation):

```
The questionnaire Patient Health Questionnaire 9-Item Scale (PHQ-9; @Kroenke2010) was used to assess symptoms of depression.
```

Which marginally improves how it looks:

> The questionnaire Patient Health Questionnaire 9­Item Scale (PHQ­9; Kroenke, Spitzer, Wil­liams, & Löwe, (2010)) was used to assess symptoms of depression.

I'd like for it to look like this:

> The questionnaire Patient Health Questionnaire 9­Item Scale (PHQ­9; Kroenke, Spitzer, Wil­liams, & Löwe, 2010) was used to assess symptoms of depression.

Any idea how I'd go about doing it?

*Edit:* Since I am very new to this stuff I don't know if it's valuable information but I'll drop this here as well:

```
bibliography      : ["r-references.bib", "library.bib"]
documentclass     : "apa6"
```

*Edit:* I tried to search around for a solution and the only thing I found was [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51881899/mixing-text-and-citations-in-r-markdown) which more or less has the same question. Asked about 1 & 1/2 year ago and no answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it works with this format:

```
[PHQ-9; @Kroenke2010] was used to assess symptoms
```

You can read more about `pandoc-citeproc` formatting here:  https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citations.